# Inline code should not allow jsFiddle links

Tags: feature-request, jsfiddle

It appears to me that the "jsFiddle links must be accompanied by code" requirement is satisfied if there's any inline code in the question. So if the poster simply uses backticks to highlight an expression, he won't get a warning if he then posts a jsFiddle link.

I think the requirement should be that there's a real code block, not just one or two inline bits of code. Or, since some posters don't know about setting off code blocks, and put backticks around larger blocks of code, perhaps it could check that at least one code block has a newline in it.

I'm not trying to address people deliberately working around the rule, just dealing with it not detecting unknowing violations.

Comment: *it could check that at least one code block has a newline in it* I think that this is a good metric to use.

Comment: `Related:` [Don't consider `inline code spans` as `code` for the `purposes` of the `quality filter`](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/176902/dont-consider-inline-code-spans-as-code-for-the-purposes-of-the-quality-filter)

Answer (score 24):

If you're determined to work around this stuff, you'll figure it out; folks have posted whole blocks of nonsense before and would probably continue to do so.

The message is a reasonable attempt to get folks to Do The Right Thing; if they don't listen, then downvote, vote to close the question, and leave them to enjoy their cleverness alone.

Comment: Like I said, I'm not trying to deal with determined posters, just the ones who don't know better.

Comment: I was under the impression this wasn't to target the people who would do it anyway, instead, to target users who accidentally use the code ticks around a jsfiddle link. though... I kinda doubt it's accidental in most cases.

Comment: Right - it's educational. And it serves that role. Trying to work around all the work-arounds turns it into something else, and will fail anyway.

Comment: It could still be useful to try to catch some of the "work-arounds" that people trigger *accidentally*. I can easily believe that using inline code falls into that category, given how `much` some users `like` to apply `gratuitous backticks` to their posts `enter code here` or to use them for `emphasis`.

Comment: (Yes, those users are arguably clueless. But then, so are the users who post jsFiddle links without code, too. The users who already know not to do either of those things are not the ones we're trying to educate here.)

Comment: The message is just a helpful reminder that will hopefully catch at least some of these cases. However, it's not perfect and never will be perfect. That's why there's still the mechanisms of closing and down-voting as @Shog9 mentions. These are educational tools as well, not punishments, although people often view them as punishments. Down-votes can be reversed if the question is edited or closed and closed questions can always be re-opened if the content is improved.

Comment: closing and downvoting is ineffective AFAIK. Users are probably not experienced enough to make an MCVE. Answers more often than not don't seem to care. So users keep posting questions with jsfiddle/codepen links and no mcve and they get answers so they keep doing it.

Answer (score 0):

I rarely see questions with a codepen link or a jsfiddle link that included a Minimal Complete Verifiable Example in the question itself.

The majority of the questions I see with a codepen or jsfiddle link basically the questioner isn't experienced enough to know what the bug is so they just paste 5 to 25 lines into their question and then link. 9 out of 10 times they get an answer. The question is rarely closed as off topic even though it is off topic by

> Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest **code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself**.

I think S.O. should take a look and see how many questions with links to jsfiddle and codepen are off topic. If it turns out 60% plus of those questions are off topic then would it not be better to just disallow links to codepen, jsfiddle? Any codepen or jsfiddle can be done in a snippet so if the goal is to have more on-topic question than it seems like disallowing codepen and jsfiddle links would do that. If they put one in just pop up "use a snippet". You might not get more MCVEs but you'll at least get CVEs and generous users can edit into MCVEs which seems far better than the status quo